# Java - attach class instance to another class instance

Tags: java, class

Trying to create a blackjack game using preconfigured Instances (need to use the method signatures provided). I have a testHarness/client class that runs through a game loop. The client class has:

```
final GameEngine gameEngine = new GameEngineImpl();
```

So gameEngine is a new instance of GameEngineImpl.

Then the client has a method to attach an instance of GameEngineCallbackImpl to gameEngine.

```
gameEngine.addGameEngineCallback(new GameEngineCallbackImpl());
```

The method signature for addGameEngineCallback in GameEngineImpl looks like this

```
public void addGameEngineCallback(GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback)
```

So GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback = new GameEngineCallbackImpl() ???

How do I attach gameEngineCallback to gameEngine? Can I just pass a reference? Like this?

```
public void addGameEngineCallback(GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback) {
  GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallbackCurrent = null;
  gameEngineCallback = gameEngineCallbackCurrent;
```

}

Comment: I have no idea what the actual question is.

Comment: So are you inviting us to play with the `GameEngine`?

Comment: he/she is asking how to attach class instance to another class instance, like one would attach an email message to another email message.

Comment: @sharonbn - Interesting theory.  The problem is that he has shown us code in his Question that does that.  Hence ... what is he *actually* asking?

Comment: Sorry guys, new to posting here (and Java newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to "attach" an Object ("attached") to another ("container") , is to hold a reference on the attached as an [instance variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in the conteiner:

```
public class GameEngine {
  // an instance variable, declared outside of the methods.
  // its lifetime equals that of the game engine instance
  private GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback;

  public void addGameEngineCallback(GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback) {
    this.gameEngineCallback = gameEngineCallback;
  }

  // later on, the engine can call upon the callback to do stuff
  public void startGame() {
    this.gameEngineCallback.start();
  }
}
```